# Record didn't get saved in database in many to many relationship

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have a **many-to-many** relationship and i mapped it like this
`FournisseurActivite` , `Activite` , `Fournisseur`

FournisseurActivite.java :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "fournisseur_activite", catalog = "ao")
public class FournisseurActivite implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer idFournissuerActivite;
    private Activite activite;
    private Fournisseur fournisseur;
        ...
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_FOURNISSUER", nullable = false)
    public Fournisseur getFournisseur() {
        return this.fournisseur;
    }
        ...

}
```

Fournisseur.Java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "fournisseur", catalog = "ao")
public class Fournisseur implements java.io.Serializable {

    ...
    private Set<FournisseurActivite> fournisseurActivites = new HashSet<FournisseurActivite>(0);

        ...
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "fournisseur")
    public Set<FournisseurActivite> getFournisseurActivites() {
        return this.fournisseurActivites;
    }
        ...
}
```

My problem is when execute this code below nothing happened to the table `FournisseurActivite` no record was added !! i put just the part where i get the error everything else get saved normally in database

```
fournisseur.getFournisseurActivites()
              .add(new FournisseurActivite(activite,fournisseur));
fournisseurrespository.save(fournisseur);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `cascade` `merge` and `persist` option to  `OneToMany` on `getFournisseurActivites()`, like this

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "fournisseur", cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST} )
public Set<FournisseurActivite> getFournisseurActivites() {
    return this.fournisseurActivites;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @fujy it works now But i want to understand why i have to add `cascade` in mapping class because in `Mysql` i already defined the FK as `ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE`